# Scrolling tabs instead of fixed tabs in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-scrollview

Is it possible to make tabs in ActionBar look like scrolling tabs, e.g.:

[image]

Because all I can get are fixed tabs like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve are not scrolling tabs, but a ViewPager. You won't be able to get the look you want using only tabs.

Take a look at the good tutorial here on the ViewPager: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

The best way to implement this is to use Fragments, and the library [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)  for the top list of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Please check: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not what I meant. I already have swiping between tabs. It's about how they look. Scrolling tabs display currently only 3 tabs: previous, current and next. Fixed tabs can however display more tabs, please look: http://cdn1.91pad.com/screenshot/img5/201204190153371118.jpg